# Using two SELECT statements from two different tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, dapper

I'm currently working with Dapper to display data from Sql server into textboxes. I have these two tables:

```
id | fname | lname  | Age
 1 | cal   | bla    | 100
 2 | vin   | bla    | 10
```

table1

```
id | fname | lname | Age
1 | cal   | vin    | 50
2 | calvin | cal    | 25
```

table2

And my stored proc looks like this:

```
@Fname nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Fname,Lname,Age FROM table1 WHERE Fname=@Fname 
UNION
SELECT Fname,Lname,Age FROM table2 WHERE Fname=@Fname
END
```

i'm inserting the first name in form in textbox and it will display the lname and age. I want the resulting table to include lname from table1 and age from table2, something like this:

```
id | fname | lname  | Age
1 | calvin | bla    | 50
```

My C# function:

```
   public void Multi(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    db.Open();

                DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("multi", con);
                p.Add("@Fname", tb2.Text, 
                DbType.String,ParameterDirection.Input);

                var multi = con.QueryMultiple("multi", p, commandType: 
                CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                clients cls = new clients();
                cls.C = multi.Read<Client>().ToList();
                var cli = multi.Read<clients>().ToList();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cls.C.Add(new Client()
                    {
                        Fname = (String)reader["Fname"],
                        Lname = (String)reader["Lname"],
                        Age = (int)reader["Age"]
                    });
                    tb2.Text = cls.C[0].Fname;
                    tb3.Text = cls.C[0].Lname;
                    tb4.Text = cls.C[0].Age.ToString();
```

And client Class:

```
    class Client
    {
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
     }
    class clients
    {
     public List<Client> C = new List<Client>();
    }
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
1-Procedure or function 'multi' expects parameter '@Fname', which was not 
supplied.
2-The reader has been disposed; this can happen after all data has been 
consumed Object name: 'Dapper.SqlMapper+GridReader'.
3- An explicit value for the identity column in table 'CloneInfo' can only 
be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

I pointed the cursor on **reader** and it says null and the execution breaks off

ANSWER:
Ive added this and it works perfectly:

```
    DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("@Fname", tb2.Text);
                var multi = con.QueryMultiple("multi", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                clients cls = new clients();
                clients cls2 = new clients();

                cls.C = multi.Read<Client>().ToList();
                cls2.C = multi.Read<Client>().ToList();

                tb2.Text = cls.C[0].Fname;
                tb3.Text = cls.C[0].Lname;
                tb4.Text = cls2.C[0].Age.ToString();

                if (db.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    db.Close();.C[0].Age.ToString();
```

Comment: Union all? you are looking?

Comment: mysql <> sqlserver

Comment: @KannanKandasamy it didn't work either. I'm trying to get two different records from two different tables and display them in form using multiple select statements

Comment: What did'nt work?

Comment: I've updated the post with the errors i'm getting.
I'm not able to display the records in textboxes

Comment: @scsimon i didn't understand the comment please explain

Comment: @Calvin, scsimon is saying mysql does not equal sqlserver, a reference to your tags. MySQL is the open source RDBMS and sqlserver is the Microsoft RDBMS, so they are not equivalents and he is asking you to tag properly so those answering can provide you with proper syntax.

Comment: Yes thank you for the info. I've updated the answer in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Use following sql:

```
@Fname nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
if ((select count(*) from table1 where Fname=@Fname) > 0)
begin
  select t1.Fname, t1.Lname, t2.Age
  from table1 as t1
  left join table2 as t2 on t1.Fname == t2.Fname
  where t1.Fname = @Fname
end
else
begin
  select t2.Fname, t1.Lname, t2.Age
  from table2 as t2
  left join table1 as t1 on t2.Fname == t1.Fname
  where t2.Fname = @Fname
end
```

Comment: It still gives : Procedure or function 'multi' expects parameter '@Fname', which was not supplied.

Comment: This is not valid sql. You are missing a create procedure and you can't use == in tsql. Not really sure what this is even trying to accomplish.

Comment: I know I modified all the errors. i guess im sticking with my original sp